# Proximity Senzor addNotification call function mutliple times

Tags: swift, camera, proximitysensor

I activated the proximity senzor in application and now the function is calling multiple times.

I don't know what is wrong. Can you help me?

```
    //MARK:- Activate Proximity Sensor
func activateProximitySensor() {
    proximitySenzorActionStatus = true
    device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
    if device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(proximityStateDidChange), name:UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)
    }
}
func deactivateProximitySenzor() {
    proximitySenzorActionStatus = false
    device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = false
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)
}
```

The methos in now called for 3 times:

```
 @objc func proximityStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
 print("proximityStateDidChange")}
```

I activated the senzor in

> viewWillAppear

and remove in

> viewWillDisappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the time of flight between every occlusion of the sensor.